# flask send_file with temporary files

Tags: python, flask, temporary-files

If I remove the pdf file creation from a tempfile wrapper I am able to send a proper file, but when I wrap with tempfile I get this error:

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

I tried to remove the .read() from my filepath but then I get another error regarding trying to read a closed file. Ive looked online at the flask send_file and it appears there is an issue with using send_file on tmp files. Does anyone have a work around? I dont want to create a file then manually remove it once it is sent, id like to keep it as a tempfile

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:
     PDF.dumps(fp, pdf)
     return send_file(fp.read(), attachment_filename="invoice"+str(invoice["id"])+".pdf", as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `TemporaryFile` as a context manager, the file is closed as soon as the block ends. The `send_file` call doesn't read the file right then - it just returns an object that makes your file be read later on, after the context manager closes.

Per the `tempfile` documentation, files are cleaned up when the file handle is closed, and PEP 333, the WSGI spec, specifies that compliant implementations must `close()`, so we can do this without a context manager:

```
    tmp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    tmp.write(b'some content')
    tmp.seek(0)
    return send_file(tmp, attachment_filename='example.txt')
```

Comment: thank you, i switched tmp.write() with PDF.dumps(tmp, pdf) and it works. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Other good option is to use send_data instead of send_file.
So send_data may be placed before file closed.